# Problems on updating ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, 18.04, upgrade, cron

I just install ubuntu 18.04 in my laptop parallel with windows 10. When I tried to run`sudo apt upgrade`,[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnxFK.jpg). After I deleted all the upgraded files and upgrade again, it got stuck here[Stuck with this package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8TFg.jpg). After some time, it shows this status [Failed status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFlPb.jpg). I tried to install that package manually and upgrade again, the problem is not solved. Can anyone help me fix this?

Laptop used: IdeaPad Gaming 3-15IHU6 - Type 82K1

Comment: try: sudo apt remove cron, then sudo apt purge cron . It looks like your cron install is corrupt. Then do: sudo apt update, then sudo apt install cron to see if you get back to a good starting place.

Answer (score 1):

First, try `sudo apt install cron`.
If that does not work, try downloading and installing manually.

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cron/cron_3.0pl1-128.1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i cron_3.0pl1-128.1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb
```

Afterwards, run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, followed by `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt dist-upgrade`.

---

Note: If this fails, consider fresh installing Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. It might be easier to reinstall rather than fixing the issue.

Comment: I tried the 2nd and 3rd commands u gave me, but still it shows failed to reload daemon: connection timed out. I really need to use 18.04 as my current project is using ROS melodic to develop. Could you pls help me?

Comment: @newbie Try a different download link. Try different mirrors from here https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/amd64/cron/download, and install it with `sudo dpkg -i cron_3.0pl1-128.1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb`

Comment: Which command shows failed to reload daemon?

Comment: when i run this `sudo dpkg -i cron_3.0pl1-128.1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb`, it shows this`Preparing to unpack cron_3.0pl1-128.1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cron (3.0pl1-128.1ubuntu1.2) over (3.0pl1-128.1ubuntu1) ...
Failed to reload daemon: Connection timed out
`